# angular ng-show doesnt show data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I would like to filter dates. Current dates should be displayed and future dates hidden. But whenever I use ng-show everything gets shut down. See for yourself - here is fiddle

```
 <div ng-controller="date">
    <div ng-repeat="d in dates">
        <ul>
            <div ng-show="(checkDate==true)"><li>{{d.thisDate() | date:"mediumDate"}}</li></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/adeling/Tb9j5/22/

I would be thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues.

-You should use ng-show="d.checkDate()".

```
<div ng-app="milo">
<div ng-controller="date">
  <div ng-repeat="d in dates">
    <ul>
      <div ng-show="d.checkDate()">
        <li>{{d.thisDate() | date:"mediumDate"}}
        </li>
      </div>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

-You cannot compare two new dates and expect them to be equal. If you try this, for instance, it will return false.

```
alert(new Date() == new Date());
```

-You cannot reference your function thisDate from the scope in each element. It is undefined. And you should access it like a function, or you will get the function itself, rather than the result of the function. So your code could be refactored into something like this.

```
var milo = angular.module('milo',[]);

alert(new Date() == new Date());

function date($scope){

    $scope.dates = [
    {
        id: 0,
        thisDate: function(){
            return new Date();
        },
        checkDate: function(){
            if(this.thisDate()>new Date()){
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        thisDate: function(){
            return  new Date();
        },
        checkDate: function(){
            if(this.thisDate()>new Date()){
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        thisDate: function(){
            return 141232741945463;
        },
        checkDate: function(){
            if(this.thisDate()>new Date()){
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    ];
};

milo.controller('date', date);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-show="(checkDate==true)">
```

This means "Hey, Angular, show this `div` if `$scope.checkDate === true`"

Seems like you want to call `checkDate()` method of your `$scope.dates` item

To do this call use `<div ng-show="d.checkDate()">`

But your `checkDate()` compares `$scope.thisDate` with `new Date()`, but there is no `thisDate` variable in your `$scope`, so result is `false` and angular `ng-show` directive will hide all your divs

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems.

1. `checkDate` is not correct in terms of a function. You don't return any value in the last `else` statement.
2. Instead of `ng-show="(checkDate==true)"` you should write: `ng-show="d.checkDate()"`.